# MySQL transaction procedure: Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, transactions, rdbms

I'm trying to update a table and return the updated value as a part of a transaction:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateCount(IN dataname VARCHAR(255) )
    LANGUAGE SQL
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
    START TRANSACTION;
        update CountTable set count = count + 1 where productName = dataname;
        set data = @data = (SELECT count FROM CountTable WHERE productName = dataname);
        select @data;
    commit;
 
CREATE TABLE CountTable (
    id varchar(255) primary key,

    productName varchar(255),
    count long
);
```

But on calling the function, I get this error:

`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'productName' in 'where clause'`

I've given the parameters the way I've found in much documentation. Also, if I hard-code the parameter value in the function, I get this:

`Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable 'data'`

Comment: The code published is procedure not a function , you should fix the code as mentioned in my comment to the previous question on the same topic you raised yesterday and provide the call statement , sample date and expected outcome as text.

Comment: Because the procedure code is not encased in a begin..end block  mysql thinks the procedure only has 1 statement and terminates at the first semi-colon encountered therefore the select does not know about productname.. ps set data = @data = is nonsense.

Comment: ```update CountTable set count = (@data := (count + 1)) where productName = dataname;```. And SET can be skipped.

Comment: To be honest I doubt if applying these fixes will end up with a working procedure - for help on that you should provide sample data and expected outcome as text. AND please don't raise another question to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SP works fine:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `updateCount`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `updateCount`(IN dataname VARCHAR(255) )
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
    START TRANSACTION;
        UPDATE CountTable SET COUNT = COUNT + 1 WHERE productName = dataname;
        SET @data = (SELECT COUNT FROM CountTable WHERE productName = dataname);
        SELECT @data;
    COMMIT;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Nothing much, just `SET data = @data =` changed to `SET @data =`.

But standardswise, there are other issues too.  The table should not have `count long`.  Trying that as-is makes that column of type `mediumtext`.  There is no `long` type in MySQL.  There is `BIGINT`, you should use that.

Also, `id` would usually be some numeric type column with auto-increment.
`varchar(255)` also works, but just that it is not ideal.

```
CREATE TABLE `counttable` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Also, if you are updating table by `productName`, probably it would be marked as a unique key too, to make sure there aren't multiple products with the same name.

After these changes,

```
CALL updateCount('abc');

@data
--------
51
```

It returns an incremented value.

Comment: I'd recommend to replace SET with ```SELECT `COUNT` INTO @data FROM CountTable WHERE productName = dataname;```.

Comment: Depending on data the select may return more than 1 value and fail when called..

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Also I'd like to appreciate the explanation